# Why is SQLite refusing to use available indexes when adding a JOIN?

Tags: sql, sqlite, query-optimization

This is related to [Why is SQLite refusing to use available indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454787/why-is-sqlite-refusing-to-use-available-indexes)

The queries to create the database is:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(id TEXT);
CREATE INDEX `foo.index` ON foo(id);
CREATE TABLE bar(id TEXT);
CREATE INDEX `bar.index` ON bar(id);
CREATE VIEW baz AS SELECT id FROM foo UNION ALL SELECT id FROM bar;
CREATE TABLE bam(id TEXT, value TEXT);

INSERT INTO foo VALUES('123');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES('1123');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES('2123');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES('3123');

INSERT INTO bar VALUES('44123');
INSERT INTO bar VALUES('441123');
INSERT INTO bar VALUES('442123');
INSERT INTO bar VALUES('443123');
```

The result of `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM baz LEFT JOIN bam ON baz.id=bam.id WHERE baz.id IN ('123', '234');` is:

```
SCAN TABLE foo (~1000000 rows)
SCAN TABLE bar (~1000000 rows)
COMPOUND SUBQUERIES 2 AND 3 (UNION ALL)
SCAN SUBQUERY 1 (~2000000 rows)
EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 4
SEARCH TABLE bam USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (id=?) (~7 rows)
```

EDIT: Interestingly enough if I do `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM baz WHERE baz.id IN ('123', '234')) AS t LEFT JOIN bam ON t.id=bam.id ;` it still doesnt use the index but if i do `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM baz WHERE baz.id IN ('123', '234');` it does. What is going on?

Why isnt it using the indexes on foo and bar?? It does use the indexes without the JOIN section as apparent in the linked question.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/32af2/14 (use WebSQL)

Answer (score 6):

The indexes are not used because they are not needed; they would not speed up the query.

In SQLite, joins are implemnted as nested loop joins, that is, the database goes through all records of one table, and for each record, looks up the matching record(s) in the other table.
Only the lookup in the second table needs an index; just going through all the records of the first table does not need an index.

With an inner join, the query optimizer can choose which table is the outer or the inner table in the loop (if only one table has an index, it should be the inner table).
However, with a left outer join, there is no choice, and the left table must be the outer table.

To optimize a left outer join, (only) the table on the right side needs an index.

Comment: While the idea makes sense, the query `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM baz LEFT JOIN bam ON baz.id=bam.id WHERE baz.id IN ('123', '234');`  can use an index on the inner table to filter the `baz.id IN...` part, but it still isnt used. Also, to test the left outer join idea, I tried `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT baz.id FROM bam LEFT OUTER JOIN baz ON baz.id=bam.id` and that did not change the query plan. (updated question to reflect this)

Comment: The subquery resulting from the view cannot be flattened because it violates [condition 3](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#flattening).

Comment: Thanks for that reference, it is good to see all the conditions listed. I apologize, however, because I fail to see how this violates condition 3. Isnt this view the left operand of the left join? Also, is there a way to rewrite this so that it does get flattened? Thanks for all the effort :)

Comment: I don't know why `baz` on the left side does not get flattened. You would have to flatten it by hand.

Comment: i cant flatten it by hand, baz is a dynamically generated temporary view (its just simplified here to illustrate the problem). is there no way to fix this?

Comment: I even flattened it to a certain extent and it still didnt work (look at edit), any ideas on why?

Comment: Flattening would mean removing the subquery (combine two left joins on foo/bam and bar/bam with UNION ALL). I don't know why this combination doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

The query planner is determining that using the indices is no more efficient in this instance. However, it is still possible to force the use of the indices by modifying the view in the following way:

```
CREATE VIEW baz AS SELECT id FROM foo UNION ALL SELECT id FROM bar ORDER BY id;
```

The `ORDER BY` statement will force the use of an index when accessing an indexed field.

The results of the new Query Plan:

`EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM baz LEFT JOIN bam ON baz.id=bam.id WHERE baz.id IN ('123', '234');`

```
SCAN TABLE foo USING COVERING INDEX foo.index (~4 rows)
SCAN TABLE bar USING COVERING INDEX bar.index (~4 rows)
COMPOUND SUBQUERIES 2 AND 3 (UNION ALL)
SCAN SUBQUERY 1 (~2 rows)
EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 4
SEARCH TABLE bam USING INDEX bam.index (id=?) (~1 rows)
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, while this query does appear to use the index when given via this command, it actually takes orders of magnitude *longer* to execute. Why? I have no idea, but I am guessing that it is performing the order by before it processes the filter thereby taking a long amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Union All are very difficult to optimize because the dbms will make temporary copies of the results.  You'll have to specifically find documentation on how union all is implemented but you can just design in a foobar column.

```
CREATE TABLE Danny117(id TEXT, mytype TEXT);

INSERT INTO Danny117 VALUES('123', 'foo');
INSERT INTO Danny117 VALUES('1123', 'foo');
INSERT INTO Danny117 VALUES('2123', 'foo');
INSERT INTO Danny117 VALUES('3123', 'foo');

INSERT INTO Danny117 VALUES('44123','bar');
INSERT INTO Danny117 VALUES('441123','bar');
INSERT INTO Danny117 VALUES('442123','bar');
INSERT INTO Danny117 VALUES('443123','bar');
```

The result of

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT Danny117.id, bam.* FROM Danny117 LEFT JOIN bam ON danny117.id=bam.id WHERE danny117.id IN ('123', '234');
```

Good Luck

Comment: while clever, this is essentially flattening the tables which cannot be done for many reasons.

Comment: @chacham I guess the create table statements were for example purposes only.  Sorry Union All statements just don't optimize because they make a temporary table.  I believe the source is out there for sqllite if you want to take a go at it.

Comment: no, that is not correct. SQLite is able to flatten the query past UNION ALL. Proof is that the query `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM baz WHERE baz.id IN ('123', '234');` DOES manage to use the index.

Comment: @chacham Sorry it uses the index to build a temporary table for processing the union all.  Which is alot of overhead.