# Does SQLite have an eval command?

Tags: sql, sqlite, query-optimization

I have a query referenced in [Why is SQLite refusing to use available indexes when adding a JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671738/why-is-sqlite-refusing-to-use-available-indexes-when-adding-a-join?lq=1) that is a compound query. When the segments of the query are evaluated individually, the query plan generated applies the relevant indicies and runs smoothly. However, when run together (via a JOIN) it fails to do so. Therefore, I was wondering if there was a way to create a query that runs 'eval' on the subquery and passes that to the outer query to force SQLite to use the query plans that would have been generated had they been done individually.

Answer (score 1):

This question is currently the first Google search result for "sqlite eval". To answer the question in the title, SQLite does not have a built-in `EVAL`, `PREPARE`/`EXECUTE` (as in MySQL), or other equivalent statement, but there is a [run-time loadable extension](https://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html) available on the official website that implements an `eval()` function: https://sqlite.org/src/file?name=ext/misc/eval.c.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your other question tells you why already: indexes are not used when they're not useful.

In essence:

- If it's cheapest to hop back and forth on disk pages to fetch a handful of rows that match a query, an index gets used.
- If it's cheapest to just read the entire mess and filter out uneeded rows, an index is not used.

Some databases (e.g. Postgres) offer an intermediary level between the two in the form of a bitmap index scan: it amounts to the second with a pre-flight check based on the index, to avoid visiting disk pages that contain no matching rows.

That's all there is to it, really: a few rows, index; lots of rows, no index.

Naturally, poorly written queries don't use indexes either, but that's for different reasons: they just confuse the query planner, and while smart the latter is not all-knowing. Joining on a union or an aggregate, in particular, are a prime recipe for not using indexes. (And that is what you are doing.)

Comment: While I understand what you mean, it simply isnt correct. The index is useful, the query planner is simply creating a bad query plan because it is unable to flatten the query (because, as you say 'the query is poorly written'). The query must be written this way however, because it is an abstraction of which physical database is being read. I can prove that the index is useful by manually piping the output of one query into the other and showing that the runtime is faster.

Comment: Furthermore, if you look at what I wrote under 'EDIT', it chooses to use an index one time for the same query that it chose not to in another instance.

Comment: Per my own answer and the comments I added to DrCopy's answer, the index will be useful if you left join the tables directly ***and*** you fetch only so many rows. It won't be if you left join the union of two or more tables (failure to flatten by the planner), or if a seq scan on is faster than randomly accessing disk pages (as shown in the EDIT in your other question).

Comment: What's important to understand in the latter bit (and in the first part of my answer) is this: when using an index, you visit disk pages 4, 6, 10, 1, 4, 3, 6, etc., etc. in random order. This is costly. Seq scan, in contrast, visits them like 1, 2, 3… etc. in physical order. If you're going to visit nearly all disk pages anyway, using an index merely adds overhead — lots of it. That is why some queries won't use an index, ever: too many rows will get returned, or a bunch of rows spread across the entire table will get returned. Either way, a seq scan is cheaper.

Comment: I dont understand why you think "It won't be if you left join the union of two or more tables." If all the tables that you are unioning have an index AND if the query optimizer decides individually that adding the index is faster than not using the index, then logically it should hold that unioning the individual queries should also use the queries because it is no faster to not use it since they are separate databases. Furthermore, as I was trying to say previously, from an empirical standpoint I see that it is faster to use the indexes, so any logical argument must support that fact.

Comment: Which part of you ***cannot*** use an index on table A or table B when you are joining table (A + B) with C do you not understand? The indexes are on A, and on B; not on (A + B). To use indexes, the query must be rewritten, either by the optimizer or (since it's not doing so) by you, as (A join C + B join C). It *cannot*, and *will not*, use an index on A, or B, for (A + B) join C, without rewriting the query. No ifs, no buts…

Answer (score 0):

Per usual you should write your queries and indexes that way so that `Sqlite`'s query optimizer recognizes the optimal indexes and just uses them.

But as your question in this case is more specific it seems you look for an equivalent of `SQL Server`'s `FORCE(INDEX)` clause.

As I have read about it in `Sqlite` there is the clause `INDEXED BY`, though it seems `Sqlite`'s community's opinions about it are split (probably because of what I mentioned in my first sentence)

[link 1 sqlite.org's documentation about it](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_indexedby.html)

[link 2 for a tutorial on that](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_indexed_by.htm)

Comment: Ya, but…: any force(index) or similar hint can't possibly apply here, since OP's two tables are union all'ed together before they're joined with a third one. If SQLite doesn't rewrite the query properly (which it evidently doesn't), it can't use an index even if told to. :-)

Comment: @Denis Hm could you expand just a bit on that? I don't understand you completely I guess. I was under the impression you can force indexes even in union(-all-)ed queries if you just force (each) index on each of the selects individually

Comment: OP is doing what amounts to: `select C.*, D.* from (select id from A union all select id from B) as C left join D on D.id = C.id`. If SQLite doesn't rewrite it as `select A.id, D.* from A join D on D.id = A.id union all [same for B]` (which it evidently doesn't), then it cannot possibly use an index; even with a hint, since there is no index that spans tables A *and* B.

Comment: @Denis put aside if this is something one would want, `SELECT FROM A` and `SELECT FROM B` could be augmented with `INDEXED BY` couldn't they? sorry I still don't get it :)

Comment: Conceptually yes, but I'd wager the result will be to fetch the two tables in full (as in unfiltered) using two index scans, instead of the current two seq scans, unioning them together, and then left joining the result just like it does now. What is actually needed is for SQLite to recognize that only certain rows in A and B will actually be useful; but the `union all` operator that isn't getting rewritten throws that requirement out of the window.

Comment: @Denis Yea that makes perfect sense, thanks for your replies.

Comment: @Denis Interestingly enough, that is not the case. You simply get an error trying to evaluate the query: "could not prepare statement (1 cannot use index: foo.index)". Sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/c24f9/1

Comment: @chacham15 more interestingly it seems the error you are getting is due to using `SQLite(WebSQL)` in `sqlfiddle` I switched to `SQLite(SQL.js)` and it did not throw that error then